# How to check if anyone is subscribed to EventEmitter in Angular?

Tags: angular

There is a EventEmitter:

```
@Output() edit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

How to check if anyone is subscribed to EventEmitter in Angular?

Comment: You can't. That's not how observables work. Please share what the original problem was that gave you this idea as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) is an RXJS `Subject`:

```js
class EventEmitter<T> extends Subject<T>
```

#### Check if any subscribers/observers

`Subject.observed: bool` -- true if there are 1 or more subscribers

### [RXJS Source Code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/c66657469dc17fbed992e273d7d121e51c00d671/packages/rxjs/src/internal/Subject.ts)

```js
/**
 * A Subject is a special type of Observable that allows values to be
 * multicasted to many Observers. Subjects are like EventEmitters.
 *
 * Every Subject is an Observable and an Observer. You can subscribe to a
 * Subject, and you can call next to feed values as well as error and complete.
 */
export class Subject<T> extends Observable<T> implements SubscriptionLike {
  ...

  private currentObservers = new Map<number, Observer<T>>()

  get observed() {
    return this.currentObservers.size > 0;
  }
```

### Notes

- Rather than using an `EventEmitter`, consider `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject`.

See: [**Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34376854/1164465)

Comment: I was using this technique but I have this "depreacation" warning:

"Internal implementation detail, do not use directly. Will be made internal in v8."

Anyone knows how to replace this ?

Comment: @Tonio: Use `.observed`.

Comment: @Tonio Answer updated to reflect new RxJS `Subject` API. The property is now called `currentObservers`

Comment: `currentObservers` is a private field of `Subject`. If what you want is to know if there are any observers, then use the public getter `.observed` as mentioned by @VictorZakharov